# Spring boot port conflicts with Jboss port?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jboss6.x

I have a Spring boot app that runs inside a JBoss EAP 6.4.0 server with a JDK 1.7, and packaged in an EAR with maven.

- In my spring boot `application.properties` (under src/main/resources), I have `server.port=8081`
- And in my JBoss `standalone.xml` file, I have `<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>`

Then, when I run my app (from Eclipse with `Run on server > My JBoss server`), It appears that the server is listening on 8080, i.e. server.port was ignored.

Also tried this:

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.setPort(8081);
    }
}
```

Simple log ensures that the method is well executed. But app still listening on 8080.

How can I get my app runing on 8081 please ? (Without changing my standalone.xml file)

I've already read the doc but that didn't help me: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port

I am very new to Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`server.port` is only used by spring boot when you do a fat-jar packaging and use the embedded servlet container.
So if you don't change your deployment model, you simply can't without changing your `standalone.xml`

you could install the STS and do a run as -> spring boot app

Comment: That's precisely the confirmation I wanted :). Thanks a lot.